# White space between table cells

Tags: html, css

I have a list with multiple  links in it. I want them to display next to each other with a coloured background and some white space between them.

First I had "display:inline-block;" but then I couldn't give the link a vertical align. So I found out that I had to make the display a table-cell but now I don't have white space because I have a coloured background.

I have used padding but this didn't gave me white space. This is my code with fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div id="frontpage-menu">
    <ul class="button">
        <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Diensten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projecten</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#frontpage-menu {
    width: 1000px;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
}

.button li {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #4A4A2F;
    width: 200px;
    height: 65px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.button li>a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 40pt;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
}
```

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0L7275dq/

Comment: What's wrong with `display:inline-block`, exactly?

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0L7275dq/4/

Comment: use a `margin` instead? padding would go within the element and get the element's background color.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0L7275dq/5/

Comment: With display block and margin: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0L7275dq/7/)

Comment: Thanks "Prerak Sola" that did solve my question. I read that on the internet but apparently that's false info. Please comment this as an answer so I can give you credits.

Comment: Added as an answer ... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `border: 3px solid; border-color: white` in your css for `li`.
You can check this fiddle link for the demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0L7275dq/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`&ensp;`

and for larger spaces:

`&emsp;`

Add the tag at the end of your text and you will get space after your text.
you can find a full list of these codes here [HTML Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Answer (score 0):

add the style

`border-collapse:collapse` to your cells and table, that **SHOULD** fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
#frontpage-menu {
width: auto; 
display: block;
height: auto;
}
.button ul {
height: 65px;
background-color: red;
width: 200px;
display: inline;
}
.button li {
/*display: table-cell;*/
background-color: #4A4A2F;
width: 200px;
height: 65px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-left: 10px; /*this is where you should mess around with your white       space.*/
}

.button li>a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 40pt;
color: #FFFFFF;
letter-spacing: -4px;
}
```